# NetBeans Platform and TinyLaF 1.4.0

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, look-and-feel

I am using the TinyLaF library to customize the appearance of my NetBeans platform application. The TinyLaF also paints the frame of my main window. When I run (execute) the application sometimes it paints the frame and sometimes it does not. I cannnot figureout what I am doing wrong. The following is the code in my Installer class that extends the ModuleInstall:

```
    public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {

        @Override
        public void restored() {

            //Set the global LookAndFeel of the application

            try {

                // continuous layout on frame resize
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(true);

                // no flickering on resize
                System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");

                // to decorate frames
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

                // to decorate dialogs
                JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

                File themeFile = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("Default.theme", "myapp.main", false);

                Theme.loadTheme(themeFile);

                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new TinyLookAndFeel());

                //Remove the tab from Editor section - using the code from 
                //Geertjan's Netbeans platform tutorials
                UIManager.put("EditorTabDisplayerUI", "myapp.main.NoTabsTabDisplayerUI");

                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);

            } catch (HeadlessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you sure that SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame); doesn't works???, interesting ...., sorry never used that